# pcasm book example

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm very new in x86 Assembly Language. I'm reading a book called pcasm and I was wondering if someone can help me to understand this code example better (It's partial code from the book):

```
32    mov    ebx, input2
33    mov    ecx, $ + 7
34    jmp    short get_int
35
36    mov    eax, [input1]


64    get_int:
65        call   read_int
66        mov    [ebx], eax
67        jmp    ecx
```

Now, what I understand is `$` gives the current address, but:

1. Why `+ 7`?
2. How can I calculate it?
3. What would happen to the number if I use `jmp near get_int` (4 bytes) and `jmp near word get_int` (2 bytes)? Is the second syntax correct or it should be `jmp word get_int`?

Thanks

Comment: That seems to be a roundabout way of manually doing what a `call` instruction could do for you. Nobody does things that way in the real world, you'd just use `call` and `ret`.

Comment: @ Greg Hewgill - yes this is does the same thing as `call` and `ret`, but it was just an example from the book (pcasm) and I'm trying to understand all of it's examples. But you are totally right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The example code uses `+ 7` because presumably there are 7 bytes of machine code generated for source lines 33 and 34 combined.
2. You can calculate the offset needed by looking at the assembler output listing (which is something you might have to turn on in your assembler) and counting the bytes.
3. If you use instructions that assemble to a different number of machine code bytes, then the required offset will be different. You'd have to try it in your environment to see what you need.

Comment: @ Greg Hewgill - `+ 7` isn't it because of `call read_int` (1 Byte), `mov [ebx], eax` (4 Bytes), and `jmp ecx` (1 Byte) == 6 Bytes and + 1 because we want to get to line 36, or my assumption is totally wrong?

Comment: @markfw: No, the 7 doesn't depend on how many bytes long the subroutine itself is. Line 33 loads the desired "next" address (which seems to work out to be line 36, that's where the 7 comes in) into the `ecx` register. Then it jumps to `get_int`, which does whatever it does and then jumps back to whatever address is contained in `ecx`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I think Dr. Carter is just working up to what "call" does... and why we use "call" instead of doing it this round-about way.

Nasm will make you a list file if you add "-l myfile.lst" to the command line.

The syntax for an immediate "jmp" would be "jmp short" and "jmp near". (there's also "jmp far" but it does something different - not often useful in 32-bit code). Nasm's behavior has changed in this regard over the years - old Nasm used to give you "jmp near" by default if you just said "jmp" - new Nasm will use "jmp short" if it fits. You might need to use "jmp strict near" to actually get a "near jmp" in new Nasm (or use "-O0" - uppercase 'o', zero - on the command line to turn off optimization). This is the kind of thing that breaks existing code. Hard-coding the offset "+7" is "non-maintainable" code. I'm sure Dr. Carter was making a point, not urging you to code this way!

As an "intermediate" between this code and "call/ret", try putting a label where you want the subroutine to return to, and putting that in ecx. If you want to "not-call" this subroutine from multiple places, you'll have to do "ret_addr1:", "ret_addr2:", etc. You have to not alter ecx in the subroutine, of course! With "call/ret" we have to not mess up the stack - generally a better trade-off.

Best,
Frank

Comment: `jmp near get_int` vs `jmp near word get_int`, which one is a right syntax? This is an example of simulating `call`, and `ret` before Dr. Carter gets into actual detail of subprogram and calling C function from ASM.